# Twilio PHP fatal error

Tags: php, twilio

So I've been testing out twilio on a free web hosting server and this is what I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Twilio\Rest\Api' not found in /home/u512189195/public_html/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Client.php on line 263
```

This is my code:

```
    <?php
// Require the bundled autoload file - the path may need to change
// based on where you downloaded and unzipped the SDK
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$token = 'your_auth_token';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
$client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
    '+15558675309',
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => '+15017250604',
        // the body of the text message you'd like to send
        'body' => "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!"
    )
);
?>
```

I've also tried without the `__DIR__ .`

Obviously, I've replaced the variables with my own data.

I've uploaded the php master library which we get from twilio documentation website. - https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php

Comment: Your script is missing the autoload function wich will load these classes. Use the autoload or include all these scripts manually in your script.

Comment: @c0dekid How do I use autoload?

Answer (score 0):

You can install twilio package via composer

https://packagist.org/packages/twilio/sdk

then;

```
<?php 
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

...

use Twilio\Rest\Client;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the class exists in the library you downloaded.
Look for:

```
twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api.php
```

If it is missing (and that is what the error message you get implies) then you need to download a more current version of the helper library.

See the section on 'Using without Composer' [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php).